# Typescript conditional array return type based on generic function argument

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-statements

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
const returnArrayIfArrayIsPassedIn = <T extends string[] | string>(
  arg: T
): T extends string[] ? string[] : string => {
  if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
    return ["foo"];
  }
  return "foo";
};
```

However, both return statements result in a type error saying either string or string[] is not assignable to type 'T extends string[] ? string[] : string', despite TS inferring the correct shape of arg in each logical branch. Why do the return statements not satisfy the return signature?

Comment: releated issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912. TLDR: TypeScript simply does not support this yet and can't understand the logic of your function body.

Comment: I'm distracted by the `arg.length` check.  Surely `[]` is an array, so why are you returning `"foo"` if `[]` is passed in?  Could you fix your logic?  Fixing it won't fix your issue, but it would stop me from talking about it.

Comment: @jcalz I had added it to make sure TS infers arg to be an array (somehow it doesn't with just Array.isArray(), which I don't understand), but you're right that it should be removed.

Comment: A bit verbose, but maybe like this: [typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKZRMsBBZyCGAngJLC4EkDOACvpZagCbFgAU+yA5gFyKVTIYYTgG0AugEpe-QcPEBuAFChIsBCnSYceIqXK6adBszYcefAUM5SLszkpXR4SNBiz6SZHVVr0mLdi5pS2FEAB9bK3EbGStwyLkxRABvRUR0xBhgRFYPADoYSg9A6wkUtIzK1y1EEQAiYDg4OrElSoBfRQr06qxEBqa6pXalRQgEfkR8RABeDTdtCj1vYkM-E1Y6ukZgOoklcbBJgCNZ+a0PZaW14wD67d3JeSA)